# How do Publish Transactions relate to Fredhopper Index "updates?"

Tags: fredhopper, experience-optimization

In order to promote content, I understand that we [send](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v5/GUID-67E14EA6-A5D1-4D74-BAFA-D86B8B4370F7) (or [publish](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v5/GUID-3605D930-9C39-43AF-9089-B0774A40E856) content) to Fredhopper, which will ["deploy" the updates to the Fredhopper Index](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v5/GUID-DB825D9D-EF94-4A9D-A18E-D0C6E22775D1) by placing XML files into the default universe folder.

From there Fredhopper moves and processes the files (using the `STJob.kjb`), finally placing the files into a "processed" (i.e. `INDEXER\data\xml\incoming\processed`) folder.

**Questions**:

1. Is the `STJob.kjb` the XML file(s) that is/are processed by Fredhopper or the definition (Kettle job?) for how they're processed?
2. How do these XML files relate to SDL Web Published items and/or Publish Transactions?

For example, is there a difference between publishing individual Components (Dynamic Component Presentations) versus a Component Template set up for Experience Optimization?

I'm trying to confirm any practices for when you want to update Fredhopper's index in the most efficient way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `STJob.kjb` is the Kettle job, which defines what should happen with the incoming XML (which are sent separately and processed one by one by the job). The default one just moves the files to the `incoming` folder where they are then picked up by the Fredhopper indexer.
2. Each Publish Transaction will result in a single file sent to Fredhopper containing all relevant Component Presentations, assuming there is at least one  of them using the "Add to Experience Optimization" Template Building Block.

Comment: Perfect. So from a FH perspective this gives us a way to adjust how large or granular of an update we make to the index (by changing how much we publish).

Comment: In theory, yes. But it can be difficult to control the number of publish transactions created, especially using the CME.